# How do I preload imports into Django's manage.py shell command?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

When I run manage.py shell on my Django project to take a peek at something there are common imports that I always want to run at the start of the shell (e.g. I always want to import my model files.)  How can I have these run automatically everytime I run the shell command?

2nd related question, when I hit the up arrow I get the "^A" character instead of the previously run command in the manage.py shell (and in my regular python shell), how can I fix this so it loads the previous command like on the Linux/Unix command line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the first question, look at the `manage.py shell_plus` command provided by the [django-extensions](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/tree/master/) project. It will load all your model files on shell startup. The project has got a whole load of other useful tricks too, so it's definitely worth checking out.

For the second question, I can only guess that you need to install `readline`.

Answer (score 4):

you can replicate what

```
python manage.py shell
```

does by just doing:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mysite import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

and you will have the environment all set up for the rest of that script.  There are some other ways to do this here too: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

Comment: In my case, 'ImportError: cannot import name 'setup_environ' shows to me

Answer (score 2):

One single thing which can solve both of your problem is [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org). ipython stores the previous executions and it can give you completion as well.

Comment: Saving history doesn't solve the first problem when you are constantly running on a new instance (e.g., heroku), whereas shell_plus does.

Answer (score 2):

Auto importing frequently used packages in `python manage.py shell_plus`

**Example:**

```
#  local_settings
SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS = (
    ('<app_name>.models', '*'),
    ('<app_name>.forms', '*'),
    ('<app_name>.views', '*'),
    ('django.core.urlresolvers', '*'),
    ('django.db', 'connection'),
    ('django.db', 'reset_queries'),
)

SHELL_PLUS_DONT_LOAD = ['<app_name>', '<app_name>']
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/shell_plus.rst

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra stuff to the django shell can be done using as a starting point the shell_plus command provided in the [django-extesions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) app, and modifying it by adding whatever you want to make available to the 'imported_objects' dictionary.

Eg if you duplicate the shell_plus.py file and add these two lines at the end:

```
# .......
alist = range(1000)
imported_objects['alist'] = alist
code.interact(local=imported_objects)  # <-- this is the original final line
```

When you run the shell using the new file the 'alist' reference will be available. 
I put a longer example here: http://www.michelepasin.org/techblog/?p=1012