# How do I rebuild a django model so I can access new methods in an instance of manage.py shell?

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to python and django!

I've created a model that is syncing properly with my MySQL db instance:

```
class HelloWorld(models.Model):
    string = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Data: " + self.string
```

When I launch an interactive shell with

```
manage.py shell
```

I am able to view my models records with:

```
import print_string
HelloWorld.objects.all()
[<HelloWorld: Data: Hello there>]
```

What I'd like to be able to do is modify my model thusly:

```
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "This is my data now: " + self.string
```

...and then view this change immediately in my interactive shell.

How do I refresh/recompile my project so subsequent calls to:

```
HelloWorld.objects.all()
```

...would then return:

```
[<HelloWorld: This is my data now: Hello there>]
```

At the moment, the only way I can see to do this is to exit the shell, restart it and import my modules again, is there a way to refresh this on-the-fly?

Comment: See this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890924/how-do-you-reload-a-django-model-module-using-the-interactive-interpreter-via-m/3466579#3466579 tl;dr it's rather complex because django caches model imports for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it's more complex than I thought. I think I could do with looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836361/how-do-i-preload-imports-into-djangos-manage-py-shell-command - so I could quickly restart a shell and be ready to play with my modified objects.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution.